# Python, Remove list B from list A to make list C?

Tags: python

How do I remove a list from with in a list, into a new list? So subtract b from a to produce a new list, c?

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,]

b = [3, 4, 5, 6]

c = []?
```

Comment: This is underspecified.  What do you want `[0,1,1] - [1]` to return? `[0]` or `[0,1]`?  What about `[0,1,2]` - `[0,2]`?  `[1]` or `[0,1,2]` (because `[0,2]` isn't a contiguous subsequence)?  Et cetera.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert the lists into a set and take the set difference.

```
c = list(set(a).difference(set(b))
```

Comment: unlike the list comprehension, this doesn't preserve the order or any duplicate elements in `a`

Comment: Why not `list(set(a) - set(b))`?

Comment: It serves the same purpose, but the method call is more explicit.

Comment: Is missing a ) at the end, but can't make an edit just to add one character.

Answer (score 7):

To keep ordering and get speedup from using set membership:

```
bs = set(b)
c = [x for x in a if x not in bs]
```

Comment: This will probably be slower, because `set(b)` is constructed anew each time the `if` is tested.

Comment: Store `set(b)` in a variable before the LC.

Answer (score 5):

Or use a list comprehension:

```
c = [x for x in a if x not in b]
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're doing, you might be better off with sets in the first place:

```
>>> a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, }
>>> b = {3, 4, 5, 6}
>>> a
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b
set([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> a.difference(b)
set([0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9])
```

`collections.Counter` is another useful standard type if you want to count multiple repetitions:

```
>>> from collections import Counter as C
>>> a = C([1,1,1,2,2,3,4])
>>> b = C([1,4,5])
>>> a - b
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1})
```