# Python Remove the repeat element

Tags: python

I have two lists. How can I define a function "remove_repeat_element" to remove repeat elements from them ? ?

```
def remove_repeat_element(a, b):
    ... ...

a = ['bd09fdf7-918e-4a5e-8338-0f6fe78fd238']
b = ['bd09fdf7-918e-4a5e-8338-0f6fe78fd238', '3c26f383-da50-446c-8613-64e1068bd57e']

result = remove_repeat_element(a, b)
print result
>>> ['3c26f383-da50-446c-8613-64e1068bd57e']
```

Could someone give me some advice ??
Thanks a lot!

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15188973/1982962)

Comment: And others where order is not preserved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) :

```
>>> a = ['bd09fdf7-918e-4a5e-8338-0f6fe78fd238']
>>> b = ['bd09fdf7-918e-4a5e-8338-0f6fe78fd238', '3c26f383-da50-446c-8613-64e1068bd57e']
>>> list(set(b) - set(a))
['3c26f383-da50-446c-8613-64e1068bd57e']
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```
c = [x for x in b if x not in a]
```

It is pretty straight forward to write and efficient enough as a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Hope this helps!

**Update**:

For more efficient membership checking, use `set` instead of `list`.

```
a = set(a)
c = [x for x in b if x not in a]
```

This would be even faster and not to mention the improvement when the `list` is large.

Answer (score 0):

```
return [el for el in b if el not in a]
```